# Is there any way to extend threading.Timer in python

Tags: python, multithreading, timer

For threading.Timer Object, is there any way to update the timer time after calling start method ?

for example

```
timer = threading.Timer(5, function)
timer.start()
#after calling start method, i want to extend the timer time before expired.
```

as i looked through the document of threading.Timer, there isn't way.

so do i have to call cancel method then call again start method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Timer` object is really quite simple:

```
def Timer(*args, **kwargs):
    return _Timer(*args, **kwargs)

class _Timer(Thread):
    """Call a function after a specified number of seconds:

    t = Timer(30.0, f, args=[], kwargs={})
    t.start()
    t.cancel() # stop the timer's action if it's still waiting
    """

    def __init__(self, interval, function, args=[], kwargs={}):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.function = function
        self.args = args
        self.kwargs = kwargs
        self.finished = Event()

    def cancel(self):
        """Stop the timer if it hasn't finished yet"""
        self.finished.set()

    def run(self):
        self.finished.wait(self.interval)
        if not self.finished.is_set():
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        self.finished.set()
```

It's just waiting calling `wait` with a timeout on a `threading.Event` object, then either runs the provided method or exits if `cancel` was called. You could implement your own version of `Timer` that supports extending the wait, but the default one definitely doesn't support it.

Comment: How do you access that `treading.Event` in order to get hold of the `wait` method?

Answer (score 1):

Nobody posted any code examples, so figure I might as well. Here I did as suggested as above where the timer is cancelled and then restarted. Using this solution will at first cause "hello world" to print every 5 seconds, and then on a rerun will increase that to every second in frequency. It also prints some Epoch times to demonstrate concurrency

```
import time
import threading

def printit(runs):
  if runs == 1:
      timer = threading.Timer(5.0, printit, [runs])
      timer.start()
      runs += 1
  else:
      timer = threading.Timer(1.0, printit, [runs])
      timer.start()

  print("Hello, World!")
  timer.cancel()
  timer = threading.Timer(1.0, printit, [runs])
  timer.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runs = 1
    printit(runs)
    now = time.time()
    print('The current time is: ' + str(now))
    time.sleep(7)
    current = time.time()
    print('The current time is: ' + str(current))
```

Answer (score 0):

Cancel the timer and start a new one.